# Error while Jersey REST service calling another Jersey REST service - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: rest, jersey

I am getting following error while calling one Jersey REST service from another Jersey REST service.Both are deployed on diffrent tomcats.Called service is running on Jersey version 1.16 and calling service is running on 1.4
When I deploy my calling service on my local machin using Grizzly server,things works fine but when I deploy it on tomcat, I am facing this issue.

```
SEVERE: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:198)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:169)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:207)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:163)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:326)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:189)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:197)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:168)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:638)
```

...

```
Loaded com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HttpURLConnectionFactory from file:/fmrkut3/apps/UAT3/venture/lib/jersey-client-1.4.jar]
[Loaded com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientRequest from file:/fmrkut3/apps/UAT3/venture/lib/jersey-client-1.4.jar]
Feb 17, 2014 4:15:08 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.SAXParserContextProvider(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.XMLStreamReaderContextProvider(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.DocumentBuilderFactoryProvider(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.TransformerFactoryProvider(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable) at parameter index 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As the bottom stack trace implies, you have a missing library; if I am not mistaken, it is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

This library might be present in your local configration (or bundled with Grizzly), and not with Tomcat.